# Bitcoin Exchange Api

Tags: exchanges, development, api, buy-bitcoins

I need an bitcoin exchange api implemented in my website.

Basically there will be one way transactions money->bitcoin and it needs to support major credit cards (visa,mastercard) as well as paypal and google wallet.

Could you recomend me a such api which works with php/js?

Thanks!

Comment: that post is obsolete because it is since 2011, MtGox is dead for example. I need apis in use atm.

Comment: I think the policy is generally to hope for new answers to the same question to be added to the previous question. Perhaps comment on or edit out of date information in the older post?

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to find an API that supports Paypal, credit cards and Google wallet since there's a chargeback issue with paying for Bitcoins in these methods. More on this [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pm8dNt6rxek).
Each major exchange usually has their own api. Just Google "BTC-E API" for example. There is no "one stop shop" solution for this.